# page source code is showing different code and inspect element showing different code

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, inspect-element, view-source

while scraping a site when I view code with inspect element code is different and when I view the source code of a site then code is different.
What I want using curl in PHP how can i get the code which I can see using inspect element.
Page getting details through ajax call but there is not href in that ajax call 
href which I need to get details of particular page.

Here is the curl request

```
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL,www.example.com);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0');
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    $html = curl_exec ($login);
```

Comment: Can you please provide some examples of what you currently receive and what you expect to receive?

Comment: No code = unclear/too broad => no help for a long time.

Comment: inspect element code show only client side script (will not show serverside script )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use the [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html). It is a scriptable headless web browser. It is based on web kit and it supports many web standards. It can be used for taking screenshots, inspecting page elements. It can be called from Php so you should be able inspect the page elements from Php in the same way as you inspect the page elements from a browsers developer toolbox. This link shows how to use the Phantom JS from Php: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs

Answer (score 0):

View Page Source = "Server side HTML code"

Inspect Element  = "Client's side HTML code"

They will not be identical. Inspect element can be changed according to clients.

Comment: You can not in php , possible by js. because it is client side.

Comment: we can see it in scrapy(python) there should be someway to see it in php as well

Comment: @HaisamHameed see Selenium, a framework for making browsers scriptable, it has a PHP API - http://www.seleniumhq.org